# Merge Arrays of Custom Objects in To Form New Object

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

The classes and data I am working with is this

```
var firstArray = [NewClassOne]()
var secondArray = [NewClassTwo]()
var thirdArray = [NewClassThree]()

class NewClassOne: NSObject {
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var picture: NSObject?
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var uuid: String?

}

class NewClassTwo: NSObject {
    @NSManaged var avi: NSObject?
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var display: String?

}

class NewClassThree: NSObject {
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var picture: NSObject?
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var uuid: String?
    @NSManaged var avi: NSObject?
    @NSManaged var display: String?

}
```

So basically I want to combine the data of the first two arrays of objects and format them to the third array. I want to base it on the key username held in NewClassOne and NewClassTwo.

The problem I am running into is that the second and first arrays have different counts. Each object in the firstArray is unique and the secondArray can be reused and I want to match them with the username variable.

Can anyone suggest an efficient method to do this? Or if there is a name for this? Any help is appreciated/

Comment: Making a dictionary by `username` should help you here. Besides this you didn't show us any attempts at this.

Answer (score 0):

Cristik is right, Dictionary should help you out. There's a thing called `Tuple` ([Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID448))) too, that might help.

Don't be confused much. If you know how the basics of making your own model class, or your models for rest APIs, then you should know what to do with your problem. Try experimenting in Xcode's Playground.

It should look like this:

```
class NewClassOne: NSObject {
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var picture: NSObject?
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var uuid: String?

}

class NewClassTwo: NSObject {
    @NSManaged var avi: NSObject?
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var display: String?

}

class NewClassThree: NSObject {
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var picture: NSObject?
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var uuid: String?
    @NSManaged var avi: NSObject?
    @NSManaged var display: String?

    @NSManaged var classOne: NewClassOne?
    @NSManaged var classTwo: NewClassTwo?

}
```